# Concatenate dictionary of lists into a single list

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

```
myDict = dict({'red': [1, 2],
               'blue': [3, 4]})
```

And I would like to concatenate the key and value pairs into a single list:

```
['red_1', 'red_2', 'blue_3', 'blue_4']
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not even an attempt? Have you tried profiling anything to see what's faster?

Comment: `[key + '_' + str(value) for key, values in myDict.items() for value in values]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to create a new list by using `list comprehension` like this

```py
result = [f'{key}_{val}' for key, values in myDict.items() for val in values]
```

there are many others way to do that

Answer (score 2):

Intentionally I've avoided one-liner as you seem to be new to python.

```
# Method 1 : As you know the length each list(values)

# as you have used curly braces, you dont need to use dict 
myDict = {'red': [1, 2],
               'blue': [3, 4]}

lst = []
for k, v in myDict.items():

    #concatenate key, underscore and value of respective index and append. as value is integer convert to string
    ele_1 = f'{k}_{str(v[0])}'
    ele_2 = f'{k}_{str(v[1])}'
    lst.append(ele_1)
    lst.append(ele_2)

print(lst) #Output : ['red_1', 'red_2', 'blue_3', 'blue_4']


# Method 2: If you dont know the length of the values

lst = []
for k, v in myDict.items():
    
    #iterate thru each value
    for x in v:
        ele = f'{k}_{str(x)}'
        lst.append(ele)
print(lst) #Output : ['red_1', 'red_2', 'blue_3', 'blue_4']
```